# How to associate and authorize a mysql DB user with a mysql DB, in mysql CLI?

Tags: mysql

In a test environment, I created a user and a DB with the same name this way:

```
create user 'test'@'localhost' identified by 'blablabla';
create database test;
```

When I came to associate the user with the DB (while also granting all privileges to the user) this way:

```
grant all privileges on test.* to test;
```

**I got this error:**

> ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table

I don't understand what doesn't match. Because `show databases;` and `SELECT user FROM mysql.user;` clues that both the user and DB were created successfully, I miss why I get this error.

Why do I get this error?

### Update for Abhik Bose:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'test'@'localhost';
grant all privileges on test.* to 'test'@'localhost';
^C
mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'test'@'localhost';
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    4774
Current database: *** NONE ***

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What is the output if you type `grant all privileges on test.* to 'test'@'localhost';`

Comment: user 'test' would be user 'test@%' -- mySQL is kind of picky like that.

Comment: @AbhikBose I updated the question with this output.

Comment: The output you've posted showing it's working fine for `'test'@'localhost'`. @Shadur has already mentioned the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike PostgreSQL, MySQL and MariaDB do not have single-username roles. The user named `test` with no hostname defined is interpreted as user `test@%`, for *any* host, which is a different user than `test@localhost` and can have a different password entirely.

You'll want to do

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost;
```

instead. 
In fact, you can omit the separate `CREATE USER` statement entirely and do:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

And MySQL will take care of the rest.